# Who is behind LXLE?

Tags: 12.04

I understand Canonical is funding Ubuntu, and that LUbuntu at least has Canonical's endorsement.  Who funds and who manages LXLE?  (I could not find information on the LXLE web site.)

For those who aren't aware, LXLE is a "respin" of LUbuntu, and stands for "Lubuntu Extra Life Extension"-- hence the reason the question is asked here.

Comment: There are other posts in this forum about LXLE which were not deemed to be off-topic.

Comment: Ok, LXLE is not related in any way to Canonical, therefore offtopic. Check the contact page of the project http://lxle.net/contact/

Comment: The page http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic" does not mention Canonical one way or the other.  LXLE is a kind of Ubuntu.  If the intent of this site is to only allow questions on Ubuntu itself (from Canonical) and the official derivatives, it should state that more clearly.

Comment: it's not Ubuntu community read more attentively http://wiki.lxle.net/doku.php and they have their own Community forum http://lxle.net/forum/

Comment: @JohnnyD - Well, Ubuntu also has its own forum (http://ubuntuforums.org/) and presumably this site exists because some people like myself prefer stackexchange sites.  The reason I posted here was that I already had a stackexchange account, and this site had more mentions of LXLE than the Unix & Linux site.

Comment: @Paul Lynch yes, but this forum dedicated to official distributives `Ubuntu`, `Xubuntu`, `Kubuntu` or `Lubuntu` and LXLE is controlled and powered by `LXLE team` currently.

Comment: @JohnnyD I don't hear anyone disagreeing with you, so perhaps you are right.  It is really not clear from http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic that LXLE should fall into the category of "other Linux distributions," since it based on LUbuntu.  But, perhaps the intent is as you say.  What happens with this question then?  Can someone migrate it to the Unix & Linux site?  (I have had other questions migrated between other stackexchange sites-- and without any request or discussion.)

Answer (score 1):

According to [LXLE website](http://lxle.net/sponsor/), LXLE Linux is a self funded community Linux distribution.
User contributions through donations and store purchases help cover the administrative and hosting cost of the distribution.

Comment: This is a helpful start to an answer, but I don't think it is complete.  The sponsor page you pointed me to talks about different mechanisms for generating money, but there should be some company collecting that money and paying for hosting, etc.  There also should be somebody directing how this LUbuntu remix is mixed.